# mysql query: how to count grouped column but return ids(comma separated) in the current group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a commissions table

```
ID Agent  Comm.
1  Agent1 $30 
2  Agent1 $40
3  Agent2 $40
4  Agent1 $30
5  Agent2 $40
```

SO I Need to count grouping  payments from the same agent and same amount but retrieve the IDs involved (comma separated)

example

```
Agent  Comm. Count Ids
Agent1 $30   2     1,4
Agent1 $40   1     2
Agent2 $40   2     3,5
```

Can I do this in only one query?

my query now without the ids column

```
select count(id) as Count, agent,comm from commissions
group by agent,comm order by agent asc ,comm asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

MySQL has a built-in function called `GROUP_CONCAT()` which concatenates the rows instead of columns.

```
SELECT  Agent, Comm,
        COUNT(*) TotalCount,
        GROUP_CONCAT(ID) IDs
FROM    Commissions
GROUP   BY Agent, Comm
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3300e/2)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)